# Loop in txt file and list content using batch file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file

I'm trying to loop through a .txt (eg. folder_list.txt) file containing paths in each line like:

```
/subdir/folder/node-folder
/subdir/folder/node-folder-2
/subdir-2/folder4/node-folder/node-folder-1
```

I need to connect to a network drive using `pushd` command and then iterate to all these paths on the txt file line by line and then list only files with specific format like "*.html,*.htm,*.pdf,*.txt".

Assuming that when I did

```
pushd \\mynetworkdrive\rootfolder
```

my network drive was mapped as Z:

Here is the batch file I created:

```
@echo on
cls
cd /d "Z:\"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\user1\Desktop\network\folder_list.txt) do (
set location = %%A 
cd location
@echo %location%
dir /S/Q *.htm,*.html,*.aspx,*.asp,*.php >> C:\Users\user1\Desktop\network\files_search_output.csv
)
echo "cd\"
pause
```

The loop starts however, it iterates through all the directory of the *network drive* rather then those in my folder_list.txt file.

Not sure where I'm incorrect. I did a lot of research on finding possible solutions however, unable to get to the cause of problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo on
cls
cd /d "Z:\"
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\user1\Desktop\network\folder_list.txt) do (
pushd %%A
echo %%A
dir /S/Q *.htm,*.html,*.aspx,*.asp,*.php >> C:\Users\user1\Desktop\network\files_search_output.csv
popd
)
echo "cd\"
pause
```

First problem - spaces are significant on **both** sides of the `=` in a string `set`. Consequently, you were assigning the value to "location<kbd>Space</kbd>"

Second problem - you need to use `delayed expansion` if you vary the value of an ordinary environment variable (like `location`) within a code block (parenthesised sequence of commands) - see endless articles on this subject on SO.

Next - the middle `cd` was having no effect since `location` was not defined *at the time that the `for` keyword was encountered*

Next - your `cd` back to root is simply being `echo`ed (I left that)

Easy way - not needing `cd`s - `PUSHD` the required directory, when you've finished with commands in that directory, `POPD` back to the directory you were in when you executed the `PUSHD`

Potential problem: The separator for paths in winbatch is `\` - `/` is used as a switch-indicator. *SOMETIMES* winbatch does the conversion. Others, not.

If you actually have `/` in the file, then you indeed need to transfer the variable from `%%A` to a regular variable since string-manipulation on metavariables is not supported, hence you may need

1. to insert a line

   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

after the `@echo off` line

2. change back to

`set "location=%%A"
      set "location=!location:/=!"
      pushd !location!`

The `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command invokes `delayed expansion` mode where `!var!` extracts the *current* (run-time) value of the variable (whereas `%var%` is the value at the time the block is *parsed*)

The following `set` changes `/` to `\` within the variable's value. The quotes ensure any trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned.

Note that `@` simply suppresses the default "echo command to screen" mode. `@echo off` turns off echo-command-to-screen (and is itself suppressed since it starts `@`). There is thereafter no need to use `@echo` within the batch.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed walk through :). I was able to make it work with all the information provided.